# how to use react-bootstrap in SPFx webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

installing react-bootstrap straightforward;

> "npm install react-bootstrap --save"

and

> "npm install @types/react-bootstrap --save"

then add references

```
import FooButton from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';

..
    return (
     <div>
      <FooButton bsStyle="success" bsSize="small" >
           Nice Button
      </FooButton>
     </div>
    );
```

there is no error detection by typescript compiler but when I run gulp serve here its runtime exception;
[image]

How can I fix and use react-bootstrap?

**Edited**: "npm view es version" output is 0.5.2 
they say react-bootstrap version is es6, is it cause the error? doesn't make sense but can't figure the solution out

Answer (score 0):

Use `import * as FooButton from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';` to import the react-bootstrap Button component. It should render as expected.